# Cx_Oracle connection issue Redhat

Tags: database, python-3.x, oracle, amazon-web-services, cx-oracle

I tried to setup cx_oracle latest version for connecting to a remote oracle installation. I was able to connect to oracle and import data on my local installation on Ubuntu. But When i tried the same thing on an AWS server redhat instance it fails and throws a connection timeout issue.

I am using python 3.5 and cx_oracle 7.0 setup oracle instant client on /opt/ and exported the LD_LIBRARY_PATH also tried same with sqlalchemy connector with cx_oracle.

I even tried installing using rpm but still shows the same issue in server

please guide me if am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

I need to close this question since the issue was not with the library it was the oracle instance which has a inbound policy for a specific ip